# I have a csv file with two different formats of date value, want them to be in any single format

Tags: java, python, shell

My CSV file looks like this

```
id       date
1602    11/23/2015 14:10
1602    11/23/2015 22:45
1602    18/10/2011 09:19:46 AM
1702    18/10/2011 09:07:33 AM
1863    18/10/2011 09:07:35 AM
1436    18/10/2011 09:07:36 AM
```

I'm looking for output like

```
id       date
1602    11/23/2015 14:10
1602    11/23/2015 22:45
1602    10/18/2011 09:19:46 AM
1702    10/18/2011 09:07:33 AM
1863    10/18/2011 09:07:35 AM
1436    10/18/2011 09:07:36 AM
```

Comment: Well, it sounds like you should probably go through the file and try parsing each line with the format you *don't* want... and if it parses, reformat it to the format you *do* want. What have you tried so far, and what went wrong?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please add details like expected output, what you tried etc.

Comment: I'm new to programming and I tried with JAVA. as of now I'm able to read the data from CSV I'm struck after that

Comment: You want to show us your existing code, and tell us specifically where you are stuck. As said: turn to the help center and learn how to write up questions; instead of merely repeating what you already said.

Comment: import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    public class ReadCsvFile {
    
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                    String splitBy = ",";
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sample.csv"));
            String line = br.readLine();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) !=null){
                 String[] b = line.split(splitBy);
                 System.out.println(b[1]);
            }
            br.close();
    
      }
    }

Comment: Your input and expected output are exactly same!!

Comment: No, if u see the input file is a mix of MM/DD/YYYY and DD/MM/YYYY. I want all the values in MM/DD/YYYY only

Comment: Then use [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). You can parse one format to another. There should be [tons of examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=simpledateformat) how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are making this so much more difficult than it is.  It seems that all you are actually doing is (1) getting rid of the first line of the CSV file; (2) tossing out any quotation marks; (3) mapping sets of spaces/tabs into single spaces; and (4) mapping newlines to spaces.

SO . . . how about the following?  (I assume the data comes from standard input.)

**sed 1d | tr -d /\"/ | tr -s "/[ \010\012]/ /"**

The 'sed' deletes the first line; the first 'tr' strips quotation marks; the second 'tr' maps runs of spaces, tabs, and/or newlines to single spaces (\010 and \012 are the octal codes for ASCII TAB and ASCII NL, respectively).